# Save the results of for loop in a list in PySpark

Tags: python, list, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function to transform camelCase to snake_case:

```
def camel_to_snake(name):
name = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name).lower()
```

So, I did a `for` loop in my dataframe columns to apply the function.
Example of columns name variable:

```
df_columns = ['colNameOne', 'colNameTwo', 'colNameThree']

for column in df_columns:
camel_to_snake(column)
```

The output example:

```
'col_name_one'
'col_name_two'
'col_name_three'
```

How can I store the result of the `for` loop in a list to change the name of dataframe columns?

I tried using an empty list variable with `append` method, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.toDF(*[camel_to_snake(c) for c in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only calling the method `camel_to_snake` but not saving what it return anywhere. Make a new list and save the values in it.

```
df_columns = ['colNameOne', 'colNameTwo', 'colNameThree']
sn_columns = []

for column in df_columns:
    sn_columns.append(camel_to_snake(column))

print(sn_columns)
```